# How to write cordova plugin in Swift with CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, cocoapods

I want to write Cordova plugin in Swift and I also want to use CocoaPods.

I've succeeded to write Cordova plugin in Swift without CocoaPods correctly, and also succeeded to use CocoaPods in Objective-C plugin.

But I've got troubles by mixture of Swift and CocoaPods. CocoaPods requires "use_frameworks!" to import Swift libraries, but Cordova plugin in Swift requires "Bridging-Header.h" (otherwise, I've got some errors about "CDVPlugin" is missing). But Xcode cannot use both of framework and Bridging-Header.

Any solutions of this problem?